# Workaround on validation bug in Backbone 0.9.10

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using Backbone 0.9.10.

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: "John Doe",
        age: 30
    },
    validate: function (attrs) {
        if (attrs.age < 0) {
            console.log("Age must be positive, idiot!");
        };
    }
});
```

If I do this on the console...

```
var p = new Person;
p.set("age", -20, {validate: true});
```

...my model gets updated anyway. How can I prevent that?

I know [there's an issue open](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/issues/2153), but is there any workaround? Or do I need to wait for a bugfix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your call to `set` uses the attribute name `Age` (with a capital `A`) rather than `age`.

```
p.set("age", -20, {validate: true});
```

Also, when the `validate` fails, you should return something other than `undefined`.

```
validate: function (attrs) {
    if (attrs.age < 0) {
        return "Be more positive!";
    }
}
```

Comment: The capital "Age" was just a typo, when writing the question. I have edited it out now. It's not the real issue in my case. But what I didnt know was that I needed to return something other than "undefined" to work. Thanks!